# Blast a opportunity

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

Could you paraphrase "blast/thunder a free kick opportunity?" I'm a bit confused by the meaning of the sentence. Basically, "blast" and "thunder" mean to kick the ball really hard, but these verbs are combined with "opportunity", so it means to kick a free kick opportunity. "Kick an opportunity" doesn't make any sense. Could you paraphrase it so that I understand it?

> Ronaldo thundered a shot over the bar while Marshall **blasted** a
> good free kick **opportunity** high and hopelessly wide.

Comment: It's klunky phrasing (common with sports reporting). It's not the *[free kick] **opportunity*** that was "blasted". The true but unstated "object" of ***to blast*** here *(**to hit forcefully**)* is the *football*.

Comment: You've got to stop reading these football click-bait journalist 'sound bites'. They're not going to teach you English. You also need to think about them harder if you do. Many of your approx 48 questions on here are the same footballese, mostly easy to figure out from context. they don't all need individual explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is sports journalism. Strict school-book grammar is very often disregarded  in favour of economy and vigour of expression. Marshall had a free kick opportunity, and kicked the ball hard so that it flew fast (he blasted it), however it went too high and much too far to one side (went wide) to get in the goal. There is a dual meaning here, because to blast (explode) something such as an opportunity, chance, etc, is to destroy it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also hear the commentator say "blast in a free kick" or "blast home a free kick. What does "in"/"home" mean in this context?

Comment: Blast in = blast into the goal, blast home, the same. If an aimed thing strikes home, it hits the target.

Comment: Isn't it obvious (even to a non-sports fan) that it means **into** the goal?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks a lot. Isn't there relly any difference between "in" and "home" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is really the same as your other questions.  Don't try and analyse too much.  I bet you know exactly what happened.

The figure of speech in use here is metonymy *referring to something by mentioning one aspect of it*. You know that "free kick opportunity" really means "the ball which he had the opportunity to kick as a result of being awarded a free kick by the referee".

Literally one kicks *a ball*, but not every expression is literal. Not only is "blast" being used figuratively to mean "kick hard as if by an explosion".  but "a ball" can be replaced with other words describing some aspect of the ball or the kick.  You will see and understand "he blasted the free kick", or "He blasted the shot" or "He blasted the opportunity".  Or even "He blasted a goal" or "He blasted his team into the final".  All are examples of metonymy.

Comment: Thanks, James K. Thanks for the explanation. I also hear the commentator say "thump in the winner" or "head in the rebound. What does "in" mean in this context? And how do you paraphrase it in order to be able to be understood?

Comment: "in" mean "into the goal"... again I bet you already knew that.

Comment: @Jembot - without intending any pun, or not much, anyhow, what is the object, or even... the goal... of a football team in a match?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The object is "the ball". My confusion is why "into the goal" is only contracted to "in?" Why not say "blast into the goal a free kick?" It's more clear and can be understoosd by a non native speaker.

Comment: No.  The object in football is to score goals!  Why do commentators talk as if they are speaking to native speakers of English?  Because a football commentary isn't an English lesson.  It's not simplified and made easy for you to understand.  It's natural, flamboyantnt and free-flowing.  There are metaphors, figures of speech and technical terminology. There are mistakes, ambiguities and "Colemanballs".  It is the exact opposite to textbook English!

Comment: @JamesK Does "in" also mean into the goal? And from the corner that followed, the ball was again worked to the substitute, but he bent his effort wide of the far post after **jinking in**.